# Why does republishing a package to npm with `npm publish` not work after removing it from the npm registry?

Tags: node.js, npm

I wanted to reupload a package of mine to the npm package registry. Which means i have deleted my package with `npm unpublish --force`.
Now i want to republish the package with `npm publish` however i does not work and my terminal keeps getting stuck at that point:

```
$ npm publish --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\simon\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'publish',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.11
npm info using node@v12.18.4
npm verb npm-session 71877a073280f6fc
npm verb publish [ '.' ]
npm info lifecycle athenic-ui@1.0.22~prepublish: athenic-ui@1.0.22
npm info lifecycle athenic-ui@1.0.22~prepare: athenic-ui@1.0.22
npm info lifecycle athenic-ui@1.0.22~prepublishOnly: athenic-ui@1.0.22
npm info lifecycle athenic-ui@1.0.22~prepack: athenic-ui@1.0.22
[..................] | : info lifecycle athenic-ui@1.0.22~prepack: athenic-ui@1.0.22
```

I kept this thing running for a couple of hours but the last line of the logs above just printed itself over and over agin and didnt make any progress.
Also - this might be important to mention - i have tried `npm publish` with another test package and that worked just fine. I assume it has to do something with the **re**publishing.

Comment: Where do you publish to? Using npm registry or something else?

Comment: Yeah? What do you mean

Comment: What is the reason not to increase the patch number?

Comment: Actually it doenst matter what patch i use. I tried several patch numbers if that is what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up solving the problem. The issue was that I had another version of the package on the same level in the folder structure. I guess npm didn't like that.